# Bulk Insert (like import) bson encoded data in mongodb

Tags: php, bulkinsert, mongodb, bson

I am new to mongodb and thinking of trying this out in PHP5. If someone has any info or has done this please help. Basically I have a an object (or array of arrays) in PHP that I  bson_encode. I am not sure how mongo db works but it seems to support batch insert. So I was wondering how would I like [LOAD DATA...] in mongodb using the bson_encoded collection of documents.
thank you

Update: ok seems like batch insert only allows array (or any insert) Maybe I misunderstood that mongodb can query in bson (including inserts). so this is what I am trying now. bson_decode and batchInsert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any reason you're not using the batch insert built into the PHP driver?

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.batchinsert.php

Comment: yes I am using batch insert now, before I read your comment. I was doing it wrong. I was assuming I could insert data in bson format from php, at least thats what I read. But I have managed to convert to associative array and insert was ok. Thanks anyway I am sure you answer will help another noob :)